A functional equation for a prime divisor finding algorithm's complexity
I wanted to estimate the computational complexity of a basic algorithm to find all prime divisors of a given number $N$.
We'll look for potential divisors for up to $\sqrt{N}$ which would be about $O(\sqrt{N})$ operations. Let's estimate the prime divisor we would find as $\sqrt{N}$, then the number $N$ factors into that divisor and a potentially composite number of the order $\frac{N}{\sqrt{N}}=\sqrt{N}$. Now, if we repeat the algorithm again for that composite factor, we will end up doing about $N^{1/4}$ operations. Continuing in this fashion, the number of operations $s(N)$ is about:
$$s(N)=N^{1/2}+N^{1/4}+N^{1/8}+\dots$$
At some point the algorithm will fully factor the number $N$ and so the sum will have finitely many terms. And that is good because that infinite series won't converge because the terms would all approach one. So, let's subtract $1$ from each term to roughly estimate $s(N)$:
$$s(N)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}N^{1/2^n}-1= (N^{1/2}-1)+(N^{1/4}-1)+(N^{1/8}-1)+\dots$$
This sum should converge but not absolutely. It also satisfies the following functional equation:
$$s(N^2)=N-1+s(N)$$
Is the solution to this equation expressable in terms of elementary functions? Mathematica's RSolve couldn't solve it! Am I dumb? Help!

Even if someone were never able to solve a particular problem, that doesn't make them dumb. Let's avoid negative self-talk!

That series probably isn't exactly what you mean, since the upper index (the number of iterations) isn't the same as the number $N$ itself. In any case, I don't think there's a closed form for that series, although it's very close to just $N^{1/2}$ itself. On the other hand, it's not clear that the series models factorization accurately, since the first prime factor found might be very much less than $N^{1/2}$, which would make all subsequent terms smaller.

What is the point of this problem ? Finding a factor of size about $\sqrt{N}$ with trial division is infeasible for very large $N$ , there are much more efficient algorithms , but factoring remains probably hard. But it seems that you are after something else anyway.

Yes, this is completely impractical! I just had this cool functional equation for the upper bound and didn't know if it has a solution in terms of elementary functions. Also, I edited out the typo. Thanks!

The functional equation looks kind of interesting, but as Greg said, it probably isn't a good model of the time complexity of finding prime factors via trial division. Let's say that finding $p\approx \sqrt N$ takes $O(\sqrt N)$ steps. But if $N/p$ has non-trivial factors, you'll find them during the initial ~$\sqrt N$ steps that you took in finding $p$.
